# Xcode In app purchase verify receipts Where to check the receipt?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I watched tutorials about verifying in app purchases receipt and one thing is still in my mind: I already got the functions that checks if the receipts are valid or not and its working but what I am afraid of if there is a problem with my server some day and someone purchases the app and the receipt will be invalid although it should be valid and it will charge money from him and than tell him that a problem has occurred with the receipt and won't provide him the content.So in what function should I check the receipt? (I want it to check before it charges the money and if its invalid so it won't)
thanks.

Comment: that's the risk u have to take..even spiderman has to take the risk.... you're just a developer!!

Comment: so if its invalid you wont charge the money ?

Comment: no if it is invalid it means that there is a problem on the server or the user is trying to crack it and if it is a server problem I don't want to charge money without providing the content

Comment: Are you using non-consumable purchases? In this case the user can just download it again for free. This stuff happens, there's nothing to really do about it. Unless you have a backup server.

Comment: Yea but nobody yet answered my question... where (In what function) should I do the check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did it in the

```
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
```

function